# Additive "Sprites/Default" shader

Tags: unity, shaders

The `Sprites/Default` shader multiplies the color with the provided tint, while I need to add it instead.
I fixed this copying the shader (taken from [here](http://unity3d.com/unity/download/archive)) and simply changing the line

```
return tex2D(_MainTex, IN.texcoord) * IN.color;
```

to

```
return tex2D(_MainTex, IN.texcoord) + IN.color;
```

Is this the right approach, or there was a better one? (which uses something like inheritance, as opposite to copy-pasting)

Also, is this legal? I assume they allow you to use it at will, but technically there's no licence attached to the shader, so I'm not sure. Maybe that's covered somewhere in the Unity license?

Comment: What do you mean if you want to "add" the color? The first return statement indeed, like you mentioned, tints the texture with a certain color but what is it exactly that you want to create? Do you have a reference or something?

Comment: What you're doing is completely fine. I can't think of any simpler way to achieve what you're trying to do. IANAL, but Unity provides the included shaders & scripts as a base with the express purpose of developers building upon them. Something as simple as a textured sprite shader isn't worth getting proprietary over. ;)

Comment: @DMGregory you may put it into an answer, then ;)

Comment: I figured I'd leave answering for someone with some evidence to back up the point, since all I've really got is opinion (which I may think is sound, but still).

Comment: not to sure on this one, but isnt this the update that unity released in 3.0? basically shouldn't really matter which one you choose i dont think, if this is the case just go with the more recent version. Might look into this.

Comment: @StevenSmith I have no clue what are you talking about. Maybe you misread the question, I guess?

Comment: oh derp didnt read it properly, sorry.  So your basically taking the shader code and changing one line?

Comment: @StevenSmith exactly. And it works as intended. I'm just wondering if this is the correct approach, or there was a "more proper" one.

Comment: well i don't see no harm as long as you extend rather than duplicate.

Comment: @StevenSmith that's the point, could I have somehow created a child "class" adding a new "method", instead?

Comment: my gut reaction would be yes, always extend, create your child class and then create your new method, something like ShaderAddition().  this way you can reuse this without effecting the api + your not duplicating code thus keeping it nice and clean,  I cant see the shader code at the moment, but you could simply inherit to your new class and create your new method.  yes more code but your sticking to good practice, so you have my vote!

Comment: @StevenSmith and can you do this with a _shader_? That's the question. I'm not talking about a normal C# class...

Comment: not entirely sure, i can only assume that you can extend the shader, such as you can extend other unity features.  you would need to test this.

Comment: I need exactly the same thing. I want to lighten up some sprites in the background to simulate depth of field. Using the tint color would be a very easy solution. But I don't know how to edit a shader. Could you help me out and explain a bit more what you did?
That would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20864815/207655), you can either include common files, but this isn't the case, or use the `UsePass` command, but is not helpful here either.

Since apparently there isn't really inheritance like with normal object-oriented languages, I'd say there's no other way to do that.